# Align KDE Widgets

Tags: kde, widgets

Is there a way to align KDE Widgets. Right now it's really hard to do it, almost impossible. As you can see in this screen shot the widgets don't align nicely, and there doesn't seem to be an option to make them, or have them snap to each other's borders.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right Click on your desktop and go to `Default Desktop Settings`. Unlock the widgets and change the layout to `grid`. The widgets will be placed in a grid now.